# QGLWidget doesn't emit signal to QMainWindow

Tags: c++, qt, qglwidget, emit

**EDIT: Okay I solved the problem myself, this is humiliating... There was no instance of `MainWindow` created in py `main()` but I used the Widget itself as window -.-**

I'm playing around a bit with OpenGL in Qt using the QGLWidget (Qt Version 5.3). My problem is the following: I have a class `PaintWidget` that derives from `QGLWidget`. In its `PaintWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent*)` I read some value from the stencil buffer and want to send this via an `emit` to the `MainWindow`. The signal is implemented as

```
class PaintWidget : public QGLWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
signals:
    void objectClicked(int id);

public:
    PaintWidget(QWidget* parent = 0);
...
}
```

and the `mousePressEvent` method look

```
void PaintWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event) {   
    GLuint id;
    glReadPixels(event->x(), m_height - event->y(), 1, 1, GL_STENCIL_INDEX, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &id);
    if (id > 0) {
        emit objectClicked((int)id);
    }
}
```

Now when I connect this signal to a slot inside of `PaintWidget` everything works as expected, meaning the slot is called. But when I connect it to some slot of my MainWindow it doesn't work. The `MainWindow`'s constructor is:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {
    m_paintEngine = PaintEngine::instance();
    m_paintWidget = new PaintWidget();
    connect(m_paintWidget, SIGNAL(objectClicked(int)), this, SLOT(dummy(int)));
    setCentralWidget(m_paintWidget);
}
```

Here, `dummy` is a public slot and it is newer called. Why doesn't this work?

Thanks,
Michael